# Why is this image corrupt?

Tags: php, image, download

I have a [script here ( its on code review )](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/95246/favicon-downloading-script) that downloads images but it seems to be failing for this [specific case ( inc.com )](http://arcmarks.com/web/source/class.FaviconFinder.php?domain=inc.com).

For comparison, here is a [case that works (digg.com)](http://arcmarks.com/web/source/class.FaviconFinder.php?domain=digg.com)

I can clearly see that the page is downloaded, it is parsed, the favicon link is found, and that it is saved.  I've taken the output and posted it to the screen in base64 so you can see it is a populated file.

It has worked tens of times before and this is the first time this specific case has come up.

Comment: the favicon at inc.com is a `.ico` you are trying to output it as a `.png`

Comment: that is not what is causing the issue.  I made it so that they mach and still the error - http://arcmarks.com/web/source/class.FaviconFinder.php?domain=inc.com

Answer (score 2):

Following IANA specification, correct mime-type for icons files seems to be image/vnd.microsoft.ico, but image/x-icon seems to be massively used too.

Source : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_%28file_format%29

> While the IANA-registered MIME type for ICO files is image/vnd.microsoft.icon,[8] it was submitted to IANA in 2003 by a third party and is not recognised by Microsoft software, which uses image/x-icon instead

It should be better to use one of this values instead of image/png.

Thanks.

Comment: Good guess, but that is not what is causing the corruption.  I updated my PHP to dynamically insert the extension and this did not change anything - See here - http://arcmarks.com/web/source/class.FaviconFinder.php?domain=inc.com